# MKPointAnnotation changes to red pin on long click

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

I found some strange behavior with long click on `MKPointAnnotation`.

I create my pin like this:

```
MKPointAnnotation *activeTRPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
CLLocation *coord = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
activeTRPoint.coordinate = coord.coordinate;
activeTRPoint.title = @"Title";
activeTRPoint.subtitle = @"subtitle";
//Added tag
[map addAnnotation:activeTRPoint];
[[map viewForAnnotation:activeTRPoint] setTag:1];
UIImage *im = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_icon.png"];
[[map viewForAnnotation:activeTRPoint] setImage:im];
```

So when I long click on the pin it changes to red pin (default). Do you have any idea why this happens?

UPDATE: Added viewForAnnotation method for further investigation

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    if(annotation != map.userLocation){
        // This is not the users location indicator (the blue dot)
        MKAnnotationView *view = [map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"myAnnotationIdentifier"];
        BOOL isCustomPin = [subtitles containsObject:((MKPointAnnotation*)annotation).subtitle];
        if (!view && isCustomPin == NO) {
            // Creating a new annotation view, in this case it still looks like a pin
            MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"myAnnotationIdentifier"];
            annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
            view = annView;
            view.canShowCallout = YES; // So that the callout can appear
            UIButton *btnViewVenue = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            [btnViewVenue addTarget:self action:@selector(pinTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btnViewVenue;
            view.enabled = YES;
            view.canShowCallout = YES;
            view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
        }else{
            UIImage *im = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_icon.png"];
            [view setImage:im];
        }
        return view;
    }else{
        mapView1.userLocation.title = [Lang get:@"USER_CURRENT_LOCATION"];
        mapView1.userLocation.subtitle = @"";
        [mapView1 setTag:999];
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented the viewForAnnotation delegate method?  If so, please show that code.  If not, that's part of the problem.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275959/annotation-image-is-replaced-by-redpushpin-when-long-press-on-annotation.

Comment: In viewForAnnotation, the code creates green MK**Pin**AnnotationViews but after calling addAnnotation, it assigns a custom image instead.  Why is this?

Comment: Sorry this was was wrong code. I updated my question.In my case isCustomPin = YES;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method shown, the only type of annotation view actually created (alloc+init) is an `MKPinAnnotationView`.

When `isCustomPin` is `YES`, the code as-is ***never*** actually creates an `MKAnnotationView` and so ends up referencing a `view` that:

- is either `nil` because the `dequeue` didn't return anything, or
- is an `MKPinAnnotationView` because that is the only type of view ever created and the dequeue returns a previously-used one of those.

So when `isCustomPin` is `YES`:

- it's returning a `nil` view which the map view interprets as "show default red pin" (which is basically a red `MKPinAnnotationView`), or
- it's returning a green `MKPinAnnotationView`.

In any case, the code is always returning an **`MKPinAnnotationView`** for which the map view will often ignore the `image` property and show the default pin image according to `pinColor`.

To solve this, you must separate the creation and re-use of "custom image" pins from "green pins".  For example:

```
BOOL isCustomPin = [subtitles containsObject:((MKPointAnnotation*)annotation).subtitle];

if (isCustomPin)
{
    //Put dequeue and alloc+init of MKAnnotationView here.
    //NOTE: Use a DIFFERENT re-use identifier for "custom image" pins.
    //Eg. Use "myCustomIdentifier" -- not "myAnnotationIdentifier"
}
else
{
    //Put dequeue and alloc+init of MKPinAnnotationView here.
    //NOTE: Use a DIFFERENT re-use identifier from "custom image" pins.
    //That is, use "myAnnotationIdentifier" -- not "myCustomIdentifier".
}
```

Some separate, probably un-related issues:

- The logic used to determine `isCustomPin` looks questionable.  It would be better to create a custom annotation class and check if `annotation` is of that type instead of looking for the annotation in some external array.
- After an annotation view is dequeued, you should set the view's `annotation` property to the current `annotation` otherwise the view will use the previous annotations properties.
- There should be no need to use tags (I don't recommend it).  The user location annotation can be identified by its class `MKUserLocation` and in the `pinTouched:` method, you can obtain the selected annotation using the `selectedAnnotations` property of `MKMapView`.

By the way, you should also remove the setting of the image after the call to `addAnnotation`.